# Regular expression for removing the page part of a url

Tags: regex, url

Can someone show me a regex that will remove the page part from a string.

My strings are either

```
/section/ 
/section/page.html
/section/subsection/page.html
```

I need a regexp that would return

```
/section/
/section/
/section/subsection/
```

You can assume the file ext is always .html and the strings are relative (no http://host:port)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
/(.*/)+
```

Comment: Yes thanks. Here it is with the forward slashes escaped. "/section/section/test.html".match(/\/(.*\/)+/). Interesting that it returns two results. Can it be modified to return the first occurrence?

Comment: Yes, "/section/section/test.html".match(/\/(?:.*\/)+/)